# Cache only the main content in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Using Rails 3.1.1 and Heroku.

I believe this should be a fairly easy fix but I cannot find (and easily verify) how to do this. I have a very slow controller (6 sec) `Product#show`, with lots of **N+1** and other things I will have to solve.

The website is a two-column website (`main-column` and `right-column`) where the main content from `Product#show` is shown in one column and `daily product` are shown in the other, including a **"Random Product from the Database"**.

What I want to do is to let the content in `main-column` that is created by `Product#show` be cached (and thus bypass the controller and win 6 seconds). I do, however, want the right column to be dynamic (and loaded for each page request).

If I use `caches_page :show` it will cache the entire website, including the `right-column`, which makes me have to expire the cache every day in order to be able to load a new `Daily Product`. Not a good solution.

If I use `cache('product-show' + @product.slug) do` it only caches the view (right?) and still have to go through the controller.

So, how can I solve this?

Comment: This is when you should use fragment caching:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching

Comment: But using the fragment-caching causes the controller to be loaded! It seems like action-caching is the right option (as per my own research) but I cannot verify if it is working so I am hoping for someone to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with fragment caching like below:

```
def show

  if !fragment_exist?("main_content")
    @products = Product.all
    @users_count = User.count
  end

  @random_products = Product.order("RANDOM()").limit(10)

end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<!--MAIN CONTENT-->
<% cache("main_content") do %>
    <%= @users_count %>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <%= product.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<!--SIDE CONTENT-->
<% @random_products.each do %>
    <%= product.name %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Thought there would be something more "elegant". Action caching seemed to be what I was looking for but then I got problems with other functions on the website (highly specific for my website and not related to this problem). But this worked, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use fragment caching, and don't load things in the controller.

If you have a very complex query, let it live in the controller as a scope, and only evaluate it in the view.

If you have a complex process to do so the query must be executed, use a helper method.

If you manage to just load lazy queries in the controller, if the cache is hit none of them will be executed.